# Installing Ubuntu on a fresh hard drive

Tags: system-installation, windows-8

I am building a new computer and instead of buying Windows 8 again (they aren't letting me use my other copy to put on my new hard drive) I wanted to know if I could install Ubuntu on a new, internal hard drive?

I have read a few forums and it seems like it is, but I wanted to ask for myself before I went ahead and did something that could potentially be stupid.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Ubuntu is free to download and install on any computer, old or new. It is not clear what you are asking. You may want to download the iso file and burn it into a Live DVD/USB. Then you should boot from the DVD/USB and choose "Try Ubuntu." This will run Ubuntu without installing, so that you can verify Ubuntu works with the components of your computer. When you are satisfied, click on "Install" and enjoy! (We are never mean.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do a clean install with Ubuntu on this computer.  Simply download an installation iso from Ubuntu.com, burn it to a dvd and follow the installation instructions here:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

You should have no problems.

By the way, I'm assuming you're installing Ubuntu on a new computer with a blank hard drive and there are no other drives with other OSes on the system.

Comment: Correct. This will be a fresh install with no other OSes on the system.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will be possible.

You can not download the installation from an empty system though; you will need to download it from another system with a working operating system (or buy a dvd from Canonical ;) )

And you do not need a dvd player (even though that is probably still the most used method), an install from USB is possible too.

Do have a search on each component just to check if there are issues in relation to Ubuntu. 2 come to mind: keep away from SIS graphics (if you can still find those) and from wireless with Broadcom chip (those are around alot). And stay away from canon printers (heck, only HP has an excellent trackrecord).

Comment: That's what I have heard. Thank you. I also wonder, can I install Blizzard games on this OS? I play a lot of SC2 and Diablo.

Comment: diablo3: http://www.iheartubuntu.com/2012/05/install-diablo-3-on-ubuntu.html But wine is not the best way to play games... lots of manual configging and messing with video. BUT.. we do have lots of good games in steam nowadays (have a look: http://store.steampowered.com (watch for the penguin for linux games))

Comment: I will test it all on my laptop before I try it on the new computer in a few weeks. Thanks again.

Comment: upvoting is the way to thank someone ;-) @user275875

Comment: I need 15 points. When I get there, you got it.